# Idiom for conditionally selecting columns from a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I use the following idiom for conditionally selecting columns from a 
data.frame:

```
DF = data.frame(a = 1:3,b = letters[1:3],c = LETTERS[1:3])
someCondition <- FALSE

# use `if(someCondition)` to conditionally include column 'c'
DF[,c('a','b',if(someCondition)'c')] 
:>   a b
:> 1 1 a
:> 2 2 b
:> 3 3 c
```

but the equivalent does not work with data.table's b/c NULL values are not dropped 
from lists the same way they are dropped from concatenation:

```
DT = as.data.table(DF)
DT[,.(a,b,if(someCondition)c)]
:> Error in setnames(jval, jvnames) : 
:>   Can't assign 3 names to a 2 column data.table
```

I've defined a function called `..` which is a work around:

```
.. <- function(...){
    x = list(...)
    x= x[!sapply(x,is.null)]
    x
}
DT[,..(a,b,if(someCondition)c)]
:>    V1 V2
:> 1:  1  a
:> 2:  2  b
:> 3:  3  c
```

but it seeks kind of kludgy to have to include my own function to accomplish an operation that is so common.  Is there a more idiomatic way of conditionally selecting columns from a data.table?

Comment: `\`[.noquote\`(DT, c('a','b', if (someCondition) 'c'))` or `DT[, c('a','b', if (someCondition) 'c'), with=FALSE]` if you can't appreciate the wonders of `[.noquote`.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate.. Please file a bug report.

Comment: @akrun, clearly `DT[, .(a, b, if(someCondition) c)]` doesn't work as it should. Why would it be a duplicate?

Comment: @Jthorpe, existence of an alternate approach doesn't make this issue go away.

Comment: Note that `DT[, .(a, b, if(TRUE) c)]` does work, but without the name on `c`

Comment: @akrun, clearly the solution is *quite different*.

Comment: @Arun I don't know that it *should* work. Should the list in `j` behave differently from other lists by dropping NULL elements? (I'm looking at `list("a","b", if(FALSE) "c")`.) Seems like it could lead to unexpected behavior in other use cases (that I can't think of...). Anyway, I see Jason has posted the bug report, so I'll discuss there if I think of anything more.

Comment: There's nothing different here. NULL elements could/should be ignored. It's already happening in operations of the form `DT[, if (condition) .SD, by=.]`, for example. On unexpectedness, we've tests to catch those cases. We'll address it if they pop up.

Comment: @Arun -- That's absolutely the key point. Also worth reminding folks that the `with=FALSE` alternative really does not provide a drop-in replacement for `with=TRUE`. Something as simple as this of course fails: `DT[, c(3*'a', 2*'b', if (someCondition) 'c'), with=FALSE]`. (For the record, and in case it matters to anybody, I'm the one who reversed the closure.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, absolutely! Thanks for adding that point in.

Comment: @arun Does my proposed solution run against any data.table rules of style or the like? perhaps unnecessary copying?

Comment: @lmo, looks great! Selecting columns copies in data.table currently, doesn't matter with `.SD` or `with=FALSE` (and it is that way because data.tables are designed to not do a lot of *select*). When `shallow()` will be exported, these operations will get even more efficient. But I won't be working on it anytime soon.. (especially since Rv3.3.0 does better reference counting IIUC from what I'v heard)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `.SDcols` argument Does what you want. In the above example for data.table DF,

```
DF[, .SD, .SDcols= c("a","b", if(someCondition) "c")]
```

Will act in the same manner as in your data.frame. You can also implement this as in the below example.

```
DF[, .SD, .SDcols=if(someCondition) c("a","b","c") else c("a","b")]
```

will perform the desired selection. In a previous line, you could set up more elaborate constructions of the true and false vectors (which might defeat the purpose of keeping thing succinct).

Comment: .SDcols does not accept x.colname and i.colname when we have a non-equi join. Is that a bug?

Comment: There are some limitations to .SDcols. What you mention is not a bug, per say, but adding that as a feature, might be pretty cool. You could suggest this on their Github page if you want as `data.table` is still (thankfully) in active development.